# Top Questions of the Week #19

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 19 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's an interesting one, this time related to hardware. It's a very simple question (I don't really think it's stupid in any way), but once you think about it, it leaves room for a really detailed answer.

> ### [How does a computer restart itself?](https://superuser.com/questions/294681/how-does-a-computer-restart-itself)
>
> This may be a really stupid question, but how can a computer restart itself? After it's off, how does it tell itself to come back on again? What kind of software is it?

Comment: +1 @slhck: For suggesting this as question of the week.

Comment: +1 for question of the week. +1 for answer of the year.

Comment: @kez Answer of the year? Where do I find that?

Answer (score 8):

[Simon](https://superuser.com/users/80670/simon-sheehan) is quickly turning into one of our top question askers and answerers! I'm suggesting another one of his posts for this week's QotW:

> ## [Why do disks fragment?](https://superuser.com/questions/292743/why-do-disks-fragment)
>
> As a part of regular Windows maintenance, I defragment my hard drive. But why does the hard drive fragment on NTFS and FAT* systems? Apparantly ext* does not, why is this? Should I also be defragmenting my USB drives?

Comment: +1 I [thought](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1096328#1096328) of this question too but haven't posted it as I don't have a specific reason and want to see if there is other fish in the sea. I'm wondering if the other question "[Is it possible to run Windows without GUI?](http://superuser.com/questions/291687/is-it-possible-to-run-windows-without-gui)" will be worth while to blog about, I don't find it worthy to propose that question now but with improvements it might or might not be interesting...

Comment: @TomWijsman that is an interesting question indeed. Hopefully the user will report back and select an answer, at which point it might be great to blog about.